# Hive null issue

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hbase, cloudera, mapr

I have created the hive table and started loading the data using statement `load data inpath<hdfs path>into table <hive_table_name>`

When I tried to open the data there are two problems

1) At the end of last column there are continuous NULL appending to last column which are not present in file

2) When I tried to run count(*) from hive map is 100% and reduce 0% and it is continuously executing. I am not getting any result

Example of the csv data is given below

`xxxxx,2xxxx 08:15:00.0,19 ,Wxxxxx 2 IST 2015,0,2015- 100.0,1A,gggg,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,RP,AAGhghjgS,DELVS3885,1ghhh63,Djhkj85,null,AGY,jkjk85,1122JK,55666,null,1,BjhkhkjDC,null,006hhgjgAGS,null,null,null,/DCS-SYNCUS,null,null,kljlkl,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,14jkjhj63,DELVS3885,T,null,1A,hgfd,IN,null,null,null,null,null,null,14300963,DELbhjhhjkhk,T,null,1A,DEL,IN,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,hgjhhjj,A,null,UK,ghj,IN,null,null,null,null,null,null,Wed Jan 20 13:36:28 IST 2016`

Please help me on this.

Comment: How did you created the table?

Comment: CREATE TABLE PNR(
 <XYZ>) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ;

Comment: When I am loading the data from local file system it is loading properly but when I am loading from hdfs I am getting the above issue as mentioned.

Comment: The line separator in the hdfs file should be \n in your case as per your hive DDL. Could you please verify this in the hdfs file